# is there a tool to make an rss easy to read or colored?

Tags: rss

i want to know and understand the structure of youtube's rss feed : http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-/Comedy?v=2&max-results=50

but it's like you see , not arranged ( please view the source )

and i want some tool to clorize it and arrange it to be easy to read like firefox when it displays the source of a webpage.

it's not just youtube feed, many feeds like this without breaks and new lines.

Thanks

Comment: yes , or a software, i have no problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://tools.decisionsoft.com/xmlpp.html

Followed by any decent text editor:

[alt text http://img693.imageshack.us/img693/1822/capturadepantalla201001y.png](http://img693.imageshack.us/img693/1822/capturadepantalla201001y.png)